# How to search for animated GIF straight from Google search bar?

Tags: google-search

I saw that search for: `filetype:gif` or `*.gif` return me GIF files but there are GIF files that aren't animated.

There's a way to search from advanced image search by selecting images and then select: animated gif.

Is there a way to search just for animated GIFs from the search box?
For example: `someSearchTerms filetype:animatedgif`.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seems to be possible in one time as you want, but here's the closest solution:

**Update:** The type now is **GIF**:
[image]

> ### Find a GIF
>
> Go to [Google Images](https://images.google.com/). Click "Search tools" and then "Type." Then check off "Animated." Prepare to impress.

<sup>[source](https://www.huffingtonpost.com/2014/05/30/google-search-tricks_n_5338470.html)</sup>

[image]

Note: There might be an extension that can do that, or that such one can be created.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I've rewrite my original question. Is there a way to search for it directly from the search box?

Comment: Doesn't seem to be possible. I updated my answer

Comment: That option is not available for me (the huff post article it comes from is from 2014, so understandable that it has changed since then).

Comment: @stevec I updated my answer, they just changed the type name from animated to gif :)

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

You can use this custom search engine setting in your browser:

> https://www.google.com/search?q=%s&tbm=isch&tbs=itp%3Aanimated

And then use in search box

> gif cat

__

### To set up in Chrome:

1. Open **Settings - Search engine - *Manage search engines***.
2. Click **Add**.
3. Fill fields:

   3.1 Search engine: **Google Images GIF**

   3.2 Keyword: **gif**

   3.3 URL with %s in place of query: **https://www.google.com/search?q=%s&tbm=isch&tbs=itp%3Aanimated**

[image]

4. Save by clicking **Add**.
5. Open new tab and enter

> gif cat

6. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to perform search.

[image]

Result:

[image]